# ParticleSystem.Play(); Not Working in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a shooting game in Unity, and I am using particles as the laser/bullets. Even when I press left alt, the particles don't show up. It does print out firing weapon on the console, but the particles don't appear. I am using c#.
Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Fire : MonoBehaviour
{
   [SerializeField] ParticleSystem weapon;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        weapon.Pause();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        WeaponProcessor();
    }

    void WeaponProcessor()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire2"))
        {
            if (!weapon.isPlaying)
            {
                Debug.Log("Firing weapon");   
                weapon.Play();
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            weapon.Pause();
            Debug.Log("Not firing weapon");
        }
    }
}
```

By the way, weapon.pause does not work either.

Comment: It may be by design, but you are using "Fire2" - right mouse button by default.

Comment: Yeah I'm using a macbook, and if I do fire1 which is control, I can't move the player while shooting. Also, for me, fire2 is left option.

Answer (score 0):

ParticleSystem.Pause freezes particles, this doesn't seem to be the correct behavior for weapon fire.

> Pauses the system so no new particles are emitted and the existing particles are not updated.

You need to restart Particle system like this:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Fire : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private ParticleSystem fireParticles;

    private void Start()
    {
        if (fireParticles.isPlaying)
        {
            fireParticles.Stop();
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        WeaponProcessor();
    }

    private void WeaponProcessor()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire2"))
        {
            fireParticles.Play();
        }

        if (Input.GetButtonUp("Fire2"))
        {
            fireParticles.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Already fired bullets will not stop and new ones will be created on the next "Fire2" press

Comment: Yeah it worked when I added all the if statements.